# Repairing Pip3 install on Raspian

Tags: pip, raspbian

I attempted to install a package for pip3, but ended up upgrading my pip3 in such as way as it's now unusable.

I got this message when trying to install PRAW package with pip3:

Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/prawcore'
Consider using the `--user` option or check the permissions.

You are using pip version 18.1, however version 19.3.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.

At this point I figured I might need to upgrade my pip, so the next command was:

```
pip install --upgrade pip
```

But I again saw the issue about permissions and --user so next I did:

```
pip3 install --user --upgrade pip
```

At this point my install of pip(3) is no longer usable because I get this when trying to use pip(3):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/pip3", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

I've tried uninstalling pip3 with:

```
sudo apt purge python3-pip
```

But when I install it again the same problem is there.

How can I undo what I did here without causing any more unintended effects on my environment?

I know about the workaround of:

```
python -m pip ...
```

But that's not suitable for me because I need pip3 specifically for some packages to work.